# Find rows based on row number

Tags: mysql

When i want to get row number 5, i do this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 4, 1
```

What should my query be, if i want to get row number 5 and 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
(SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4, 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 6, 1)
```

If you don't have an index on `id` (and even in some cases where you do), a more efficient method would use variables:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as rn
      FROM table CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0) params
      ORDER BY id DESC
     ) t
WHERE rn IN (5, 7);
```

This only sorts the data once.

Comment: ok, first one works, second doesnt. it gives an error. i am looking for something like "WHERE row_number(specific order) IN (5, 7, 18, 19, 20)".
first is ok but it becomes a long query when i increase numbers.

Comment: @junior7256 . . . Both methods require an index on `id`.  However, if you have a large table, neither is going to have spectacular performance for large offsets.

Comment: i want to choose 5 rows like 5, 7, 18, 25, 30. i cant write "id in (5, 7, 18, 25, 30)" because those ids might not exist. so i need to select based on its row number of specific order. i can use your first method then i have to right it 5 times and use "UNION ALL" 4 times. I just want an alternative query which will give me the same result.

Comment: @junior7256 . . . The second method should work fine for this case.

Comment: i wonder what cross join does here, i replace it with inner join it still works, seems like the type of join is irrelevant here but it does some work which i dont know

Comment: @junior7256 . . . It is a MySQL (mis)feature that allows `join` with no `on` clause.